# Question about this SQL Server query of mine

Tags: sql, sql-server, select, count

I have a table in SQL Server 2008 which has 2 columns like this:

[image: input and output]

- If 1 value random show 1 time in column A or B, i dont move value column A and B. ** If 1 value random show 1 more time in colume B, i will move value fromcolumn B to column A, and value from column A to column B. ** If 1 value random show 1 more time in column A, i still dont move value column A and B

I have tried count but not getting this to implement.

I need to do this all in SQL.

My query demo [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=6b0047070be8507fee73f02dca28911f)

```
Select columnA,columnB
from myTable t1
Where t1.columnA in (
select columnA
from myTable
group by columnA
Having count(*)>1)
union
Select columnB,columnA
from myTable t1
Where t1.columnB in (
select columnB
from myTable
group by columnB
Having count(*)>1)
```

My query has 1 error 
Rows 7, 10 and 12 don't show. Input 9 rows, output only 6 rows. Missing:

```
('H','A')
('Y','L')
('M','N')
```

I require a result of the full 9 rows.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/215874/discussion-on-question-by-danh-tran-quoc-question-about-this-sql-server-query-of).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a way to do it. I break this up with WITH blocks so you can better see the stages:

```
--this will turn the data into a single column so we can effectively count e.g. the Y to be 4
WITH xc AS (
  SELECT letter, COUNT(*) ct
  FROM
    (
      SELECT columnA as letter FROM myTable
      UNION ALL
      SELECT columnB FROM myTable
    ) l
  GROUP BY letter
),
--this joins the counts back to the main table twice, so we can know the letter in
--each column but also how many times that letter occurs anywhere
--we must join twice because we have two columns. If we instead used one join and OR
--it would cause extra rows to appear, which we don't want
 j AS (
  SELECT myTable.ColumnA, myTable.ColumnB, ac.ct as act, bc.ct as bct
  FROM myTable
  INNER JOIN xc ac ON ac.letter = myTable.ColumnA
  INNER JOIN xc bc ON bc.letter = myTable.ColumnB
)

--now we use the "count of column a" (act) and "could of column b" (bct) to decide
--"if column a count > column b count, put column a else b" and its inverse logic
--"if column a count < column b count, put column a else b"
--but this doesnt cater for if both are equally 1 (like M,N) so we extend the logic
--of the first with an >=
SELECT 
  CASE WHEN j.act >= j.bct THEN j.columnA ELSE j.columnB END as columngroup, 
  CASE WHEN j.act < j.bct THEN j.columnA ELSE j.columnB END as columnx 
FROM j
```

It wasn't stated what to do if you have a source row that is eg A,Y where both are 4, by the way, so this query in that case would put A,Y

Edit:

You said M,N and N,M are to be considered as duplicate, in which case we could try replacing `j` query with:

```
  SELECT DISTINCT
    CASE WHEN m.columnA < m.columnB THEN m.columnA ELSE m.columnB END as columnA, 
    CASE WHEN m.columnA < m.columnB THEN m.columnB ELSE m.columnA END as columnB, 
    ac.ct as act, 
    bc.ct as bct
  FROM myTable m
  INNER JOIN xc ac ON ac.letter = m.ColumnA
  INNER JOIN xc bc ON bc.letter = m.ColumnB
```

It flips N,M -> M,N then uses DISTINCT to remove it

Comment: can you help me? i found 1 error case in your querry, exam: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=e187b6cea6124b84e1d1fae1b63c7af1     output error in row 5 and 6. IF 2 row like (exam ('M','N') and ('N','M')) i will stick it is double and i want to view only 1 row

Comment: But they are different rows; It's not so much an error case in the query; it was never stated in the original question what to do if both letters appear twice and the original data didn't handle that case. I'm still not really clear what you want to do.. is M,N a duplicate of N,M? in that case we need a step to remove the duplicates, and probably best way to do that is to flip them around so N,M becomes M,N and distinct them when we join

Comment: Tks for your help, i will delete duplicate row, after that i will use your query. Tks very much